# Authentication in Elasticsearch using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, python-requests

I want to use Python in Elasticsearch. So I wrote an Authentication code in Python for Elasticsearch. But I'm getting the error "TypeError: 'Session' object is not callable". Here's the code:

```
import requests
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
uname = 'elastic'
pswd = 'elastic'
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(uname, pswd)
res = requests.get('http://localhost:9200',auth=session)
print(res.content)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why torture yourself with requests when there are better wrapper around. There are Pyelasticsearch and elasticsearch for python,

Comment: May you please add `requests` as tag to your question?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of sessions you can directly use following method to connect to elasticsearch server:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth 
from pprint import pprint 

username = 'elastic'
password = 'elastic'

response = requests.get('http://localhost:9200', auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))

pprint(response.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you wouldn't use the elasticsearch python client library.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

# you can use RFC-1738 to specify the url
es = Elasticsearch(['https://user:secret@localhost:443'])

# ... or specify common parameters as kwargs

es = Elasticsearch(
    ['localhost', 'otherhost'],
    http_auth=('user', 'secret'),
    scheme="https",
    port=443,
)

# SSL client authentication using client_cert and client_key

from ssl import create_default_context

context = create_default_context(cafile="path/to/cert.pem")
es = Elasticsearch(
    ['localhost', 'otherhost'],
    http_auth=('user', 'secret'),
    scheme="https",
    port=443,
    ssl_context=context,
)
```

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html

Once you have the elasticsearch object it is easy to query your index

```
res = es.get(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet')
print(res['_source'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the elasticsearch library to connect.

Here is an example:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(['hostname:port'],http_auth=('username','password'))
#check if it exists...
if es.exists(index="test",doc_type="test",id="1234"):
    es.update(index="test",doc_type="test",id="1234",body{"doc": {"hi":"data"}})
else:
    es.create(index="test",doc_type="test",id="1234",body={"hi":"data"})
```

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/

remove the session object and try this out

```
requests.get('url', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I made this change y'day & the code ran. But now when I try it again it is giving me some error. Since I'm very new to Python & Elasticsearch, I can't get what is the error. This is the error:  
                 ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000023B52C0FE10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)). How do I resolve this?

Comment: I guess, the error says Max retries exceeded with url. Check wheather  the API call have some limit per day or something like that. It may occurs because of that also

Comment: I suggest you to use native elasticsearch api in python. refer this https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Session` object, first let's clarify [what is it for](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/):

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests.

This is how you could change your code:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(uname, pswd)
res = session.get('http://localhost:9200')
```

And the `get` will use `auth` defined above it implicitly.

Check the page linked above, there are plenty examples.

And if you don't intend to reuse the connection, you can drop `Session` and go with `auth` in the `get`, like [Narenda suggests in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50367121/5095957).

Comment: I'm getting a new error now: ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000023B52C0FE10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)). How can I resolve this? Thanks

Comment: This means that you are probably making too many requests/connections. What does the elasticsearch log say?

Comment: C:\Users\kailash.sharma\Downloads\elasticsearch-6.2.2\elasticsearch-6.2.2\logs. There are no log files in this folder. Is there any other way to check the elasticsearch log? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way to do this.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
res = requests.get(url="url", auth=HTTPBasicAuth("username", "password"))
print(res.json())
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting a new error now: ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000023B52C0FE10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)). How can I resolve this? Thanks

Comment: @vadirajjahagirdar didn't work for me,, still got same error like upper comment..

Answer (score 0):

First create a Basic header auth token based from your username and pass using 
base64 module, if you dont know how to use it just create Basic Authentication Header [Here](https://www.blitter.se/utils/basic-authentication-header-generator/):

After doing so, create a dictionary which would be passed as the authentication header. See sample code below:

```
  import requests

  #username = elastic password = elastic
  auth_token = 'ZWxhc3RpYzplbGFzdGlj'
  head = head = {
  'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf8',
  'Authorization' : 'Basic %s' % auth_token,
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 
   Firefox/24.0'
  }

  res = requests.get('http://localhost:9200', header=head)
  print(res.json())
```